# Class not registered (0x80040154) on my own COM component

Tags: c++, dll, com, registry

I am learning basics in COM, so I try to write simple COM component in VS2010 C++ Windows 7.
I created dll for component, registered it using following REG-file:

```
REGEDIT 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Math.Component.1 = Chapter 6 Math Component
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Math.Component.1\CurVer = Math.Component.1 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Math.Component.1\CLSID = {A888F560-58E4-11d0-A68A-0000837E3100}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{A888F560-58E4-11d0-A68A-0000837E3100} = Chapter 6 Math Component 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{A888F560-58E4-11d0-A68A-0000837E3100}\ProgID = Math.Component.1 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{A888F560-58E4-11d0-A68A-0000837E3100}\VersionIndependentProgID = Math.Component 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{A888F560-58E4-11d0-A68A-0000837E3100}\InprocServer32 = D:\Proga\COM\Debug\server.dll 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{A888F560-58E4-11d0-A68A-0000837E3100}\NotInsertable
```

In dll I exported (stubs for last two)

```
DllGetClassObject    
DllCanUnloadNow      
DllRegisterServer    
DllUnregisterServer
```

In my COM client `CLSIDFromProgID( szWideProgID, &clsid );` works as expected, returning `{A888F560-58E4-11d0-A68A-0000837E3100}`.

But when I try to get access to IClassFactory REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG `CoGetClassObject(clsid, CLSCTX_INPROC, NULL, IID_IClassFactory, (void **)&pCF)` I get (0x80040154) error.

Both server and client compiled for Win32 target platform (although I tried x64 too). Source code I got from tutorial, so I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Why don't you use regsvr32.exe to register your component?

Comment: Chances are high it is Win32/x64 issue, but since you seem to build it from the ground off there are many ways you can break it otherwise. There is no evidence you even have class factory for this CLSID. Post more code, both server and client side. If you're on 64-bit system, it makes sense to do everything in 64-bit domain, for starters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you found no doubt is *old*, written long before 64-bit Windows came around.  Registry keys need to be written to HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes for 32-bit COM servers, to HKLM\Software\Classes for 64-bit COM servers.  Your .reg file isn't going to take care of that.  You must avoid the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT alias and replace it with the explicit HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes to avoid accidents.

Use the SysInternals' ProcMon utility if you still have problems, you'll see your test program searching for the registry keys and the DLL.